# The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'. What am I doing wrong? Baby Flutterer Here

Tags: list, flutter, dart, box, flutter-hive

I am trying to create a list of type `User`, and if that list is not empty, provide the next User in the list. I've read as many Flutter docs as my brain can hold, and I'm at a loss.

```
class _SwipePageState extends State<SwipePage> implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  getUsers() async {
    Box box = await Hive.openBox('usersBox');
    swipableUsers = box.values.toList();
  }

  List swipableUsers = <User>[];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
          child: Container(color: Colors.transparent),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              swipableUsers.isEmpty
                  ? const Text('No more users')
                  : Stack(children: swipableUsers.map(buildUser).toList()),
              Expanded(child: Container()),
              const BottomButtonsWidget()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget buildUser(User currentUser) {
    int userIndex = swipableUsers.indexOf(currentUser);
    bool isUserInFocus = userIndex == swipableUsers.length - 1;
    //Do other stuff with currentUser
```

The error is at `: Stack(children: swipableUsers.map(buildUser).toList()),` and the error is the title of this question, `The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'`

Is there any chance to save my little app, or have I tangled things so much it's hopeless? Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Comment: List swipableUsers = <User>[]; this is list of user data type and here u want to put list of widgets try to make changes

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a list of widgets using the swipableUsers variable, but you are returning the list of User to the Stack's children attribute.Try this instead:

```
Stack(children: List.generate(swipableUsers.length,(index)=>buildUser(swipableUsers[index])))
```